# Apache throws Error 403 while trying to access copied folder on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, wamp, lamp

I recently installed apache server via lamp on ubuntu, I tried to copy into /var/www a directory that includes scripts that I created on windows wampserver. 
For some reason while trying to access this directory I get 403 Forbidden error.
Can someone help me please?

Recent apache log -

```
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.html denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.cgi denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.pl denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.php denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.xhtml denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /cms-dev/index.htm denied
[Fri Jul 27 08:25:31 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Post the recent content of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @Bart fixed that. Thanks for the replay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ubuntu is doing some hard time and the only solution is that everytime you copy files to the folder you must run the following script in the terminal -

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

Comment: Damn that is a shame that's the solution, but I am glad this workaround resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need write permissions for copying files into the var folder, also I suggest copying it as root, (with sudo cp file_name), because changing permissions of var and its subfolders for normal users are not recommended.

Comment: I'm the admin of the computer, I installed ubuntu and i'm the primary user. How for god sake I grant root access to my user?

Comment: dam it for god sake, now I can't delete the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it as below:

```
sudo usermod -a -G <username> www-data
sudo chown :www-data /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+rwX /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Then try to re-login.